# Data is lost when passing it down more than two components

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I've got three Polymer-components (Polymer 1.2).
**They all sit in their own files** therefore `is-logged-in` and `login-name` have to be passed from one component to another.

I put them together here so you can understand my problem more easily:

```
<component1 is-logged-in="true" login-name="Cool Cat">
  <component2 is-logged-in="{{isLoggedIn}}" login-name="{{loginName}}">
    <component3 is-logged-in="{{isLoggedIn}}" login-name="{{loginName}}"></component3>
  </component2>
</component1>
```

All 3 components have these properties:

```
properties: {
  isLoggedIn: {
    type: Boolean,
    value: false
  },
  loginName: {
    type: String,
    value: ""
  }
}
```

`document.querySelector("component2").loginName` is `Cool Cat` but
`document.querySelector("component3").loginName` is just an empty string.

When checking the DOM `is-logged-in` and `login-name` don't appear anymore starting at `<component2>`

**How can I pass the data on to component3 ?**

Comment: Try only define the type of properties, without setting default `value`. I think the problem in it

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(this.loginName)` inside of the elements? I don't believe `document.querySelector` will search the shadow DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `{{ }}` bindings have to live in `template`, and it's the template which **identifies the scope** of the values. Other parent-child relationships do not define scope.

In your example, all the `component-1/2/3` are in the same template, and therefore in the same scope. Setting properties of `component-1` has no effect on `component-2` and `component-3`, they are not bound together.

In other words, the `{{isLoggedIn}}` and `{{loginName}}` macros are binding to properties in the scope identified by the containing template (the scope is usually an element, but can also be a `dom-repeat` or other specialized template).

I don't expect this is actually want you want, but for clarity, something like this would work:

```
<dom-module id="component-0">
  <template>
    <component-1 is-logged-in="{{isLoggedIn}}" login-name="{{loginName}}">
      <component-2 is-logged-in="{{isLoggedIn}}" login-name="{{loginName}}">
        <component-3 is-logged-in="{{isLoggedIn}}" login-name="{{loginName}}"></component-3>
      </component-2>
    </component-1>
...
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'component-0',
    properties {
      isLoggedIn: {value: true},
      loginName: {value: "cool-cat"}
    }
</script>
```

All the `{{ }}` bindings are in the `component-0` scope, so setting the values in that scope sets the values to all the bindings.

Fwiw, you will probably also have an easier time if you aggregate the shared data into an object.

```
    <component-1 login="{{login}}">
      <component-2 login="{{login}}">
        <component-3 login="{{login}}"></component-3>
```

Where e.g. `login = {isLoggedIn: true, loginName: "cool-cat"}`.

The idea that the data must be *passed from one component to another* is not true in this construction. If your goal is just to get the data to `component-3`, you can bind the data directly and ignore 1 and 2.

The only time data must be passed from one component to another is when crossing scopes (a *scope* defines a boundary for data, so hopefully this make sense).